# "On" is optional with time expressions, no?

Tags: prepositions, american-english

I say "I don't have any events June 1st" and "I don't have any events on June 1st" are both acceptable grammatically. The rest of the group, which includes a couple people calling themselves linguists, says only the second is correct, i.e. you can't drop the preposition. What do authorities say on this?

Comment: Although I've edited this to remove the request for opinion, it would be helpful to edit the tags to indicate which dialect of English you're talking about. Dropping a preposition may be more acceptable in some than others.

Comment: American English

Answer (score 0):

The phrase in its original glory is 
*You do not have events occurring on June first*.

Or  *You do not have events happening on June first*.

If your *linguist* friends think it disgraceful to drop the preposition then ask them what is *happening* to the verb preceding it. 
Don't let them know that *you* know that such words tend to drop out of spoken English as it shortens the speech from the more detailed written English. There are many such word usages stranded from any sensible explanation.

*Happening June 1st* is perfectly suitable usage anywhere I go.